# htmlentities on all text nodes of XHTML doc

Tags: php, encoding, domdocument, html-entities

Trying to encode all text nodes of an XHTML doc with numerical entities. Using saveXML() gives me the hex values, but I want the `&#1234;` strict numerical values. It also doesn't encode dashes and does some weird things like turning © into `&#xC2;&#xA9;` (equiv of `&Acirc;&copy;`). I haven't used DOMDocument in a bit so this is probably a mess and I'm guessing I have some character encoding issues here. Here's what I've gotten so far:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
// load file
$doc->load($input);
// options
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
$doc->resolveExternals = true;
$doc->formatOutput = true;

// new xPath
$xp = new DOMXPath($doc);
// set ns for xhtml
$xp->registerNamespace("html", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml");
// get all nodes
$q = "//body/*";
$nodes = $xp->query($q);

foreach ($nodes as $n) { 
    $children = $n->childNodes; 
    foreach ($children as $child) { 
        echo htmlentities($child->nodeValue,ENT_QUOTES|ENT_XHTML,"UTF-8",false);
    }
}
```

Just echoing out values at this point to check. Some things like dashes are not getting encoded and need to be and it is still using entities like `&frac12;` rather than `&#189;`.

The documents may already contain entities so they can't be double encoded, but still need to be changed to numerical values. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I've fought a similar battle and basically gave up and manually created a list of swap values for strtr();

```
$child->nodeValue = strtr($child->nodeValue, array('&frac12;'=>'&#189;', '&#xC2;&#xA9;'=>'&#169;'));
```

Less than ideal, probably redundant, but it gave me exactly what I wanted, when I wanted it.